# 400 response when posting Checkout request to Google Checkout API

Tags: java, xml, google-checkout

While I've integrated several payment processors and shopping carts in the past, this Google Checkout API integration is not going well for me. I get a 400 response from Google, even when I use the diagnostic link. I'm sure something's wrong in my URL, but I can't seem to figure out what. I'm using a sandbox Merchant ID and Key.

Can someone help me see what I'm doing to get this 400 response, please?

I am using Java and posting from a server thus I'm calling the server to server API link:

```
https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/merchantCheckout/Merchant/%SANDBOXID%

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkout-shopping-cart xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2">
    <shopping-cart>
        <merchant-private-data>
            <merchant-note>8Ra8fw4tBaOdP4v3lseykKO6crR0dFqhzWV0EmqKuVuQaN1w0mcScAAR71pbexXlVnrwpP8wNzehuc7wz3KO9JM6xfedW8106olarCZcZBs=</merchant-note>
        </merchant-private-data>
        <items>
            <item-name>MyName : MySubname</item-name>
            <item-description>Weigh in on this year's...</item-description>
            <unit-price currency="USD">100</unit-price>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
         </items>
     </shopping-cart>
</checkout-shopping-cart>
```

I am using Java to post this data. In the code below, the url above is sandboxLink in the code and checkReq is the XML post...

```
    public static String postCheckoutReqData(String userID, String gameName, boolean test) {

    String checkRequest = GoogleCheckoutXML.getCheckoutRequestXML(userID, gameName);

    if(checkRequest.indexOf("error,") != -1) return checkRequest;

    URL url = null;
    try {           
        String baseCodeString;          
        if(test) {
            url = new URL(GoogleCheckoutXML.sandboxLink + GoogleCheckoutXML.sandboxMerchID);
            baseCodeString = GoogleCheckoutXML.sandboxMerchID + ":" + GoogleCheckoutXML.sandboxMerchKey;
        }
        else {
            url = new URL(GoogleCheckoutXML.productionLink + GoogleCheckoutXML.merchantID);
            baseCodeString = GoogleCheckoutXML.merchantID + ":" + GoogleCheckoutXML.merchantKey;
        }
        //url = new URL(GoogleCheckoutXML.diagnose);
        byte[] bytes = (baseCodeString.getBytes());
        baseCodeString = new Base64().encodeAsString(bytes);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();          
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + baseCodeString);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(checkRequest);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line + rd.readLine();
        }

        wr.close();
        rd.close();
        return line;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error,Purchase Error posting communcation failed";
    }
```

The actual stack trace in Tomcat is:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/merchantCheckout/Merchant/[withheld]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1612)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at com.[withheld]..GoogleCheckoutXML.postCheckoutReqData(GoogleCheckoutXML.java:194)
at com.[withheld]...l.getCheckoutLink(DubQueryImpl.java:270)
at com.[withheld]....GenerateCheckoutLinkServlet.doGet(GenerateCheckoutLinkServlet.java:56)
at com.[withheld]...doPost(GenerateCheckoutLinkServlet.java:73)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same (or a similar) problem ...

Comment: @Nat Sorry I missed this. I never did solve it. The client's needs changed and so I didn't need to continue down the path. I still have the code awaiting potential resurrection if though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved a similar issue - it may, or may not, be yours ...

1. Check the return code:

   int code = conn.getResponseCode();  // Integer (would be 400 in the case you give above)
   \String msg = conn.getResponseMessage();  // String (would be "Bad Request" in the case you give above
2. Check for further details

   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getErrorStream());

   Read in to see what further information is being provided - I have found it to be quite helpful!
3. In my case, my carefully prepared xml was losing the quotation marks somewhere along the way, trashing the `<xml version="1.0" ... >` right at the start and wreaking havoc from then onwards ...